# Error in Eclipse - Mainclass not found

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point

I'm new in programing and I like it pretty much. I've just downloaded Eclipse and I got an error I can't help me with. Unfortunately it's in German but the meaning is something like: "Main class not found" - "Fehler: Hauptklasse  konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden"

I understand that it has something to do with "`public static void main(String [] args)`".
Due to the fact that this is totally new to me it would be cool you could assist me.

Below the error source code;

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Light here.
 * 
 * @author (Sunny)
 * @version (31.01.2014)
 */

public class Elevator {
    // Variables

    int maxCarr; // max. carry in KG
    int currentCarr; // current state of carry measured in people
    boolean fillCondition; // filed or empty - value false = empty
    int currentStage; // stage where elevator remains


    // Constructor
    public Elevator() // initiation
    {
        maxCarr = 1600;
        currentCarr = 0;
        fillCondition = false;
        currentStage = 0;
        System.out.println("**********");
        System.out.println("*        *");
        System.out.println("*        *");
        System.out.println("*        *");
        System.out.println("*        *");
        System.out.println("*        *");
        System.out.println("*        *");
        System.out.println("**********");
    }

    public int  (int carry) // Setting carry into the elevator
    {
        currentCarr = carry;
        if (currentCarr != 0) {
            fillCondition = true;
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void move(int stage) {
        if (stage > currentStage) {
            System.out.println("moving up");
            currentStage = stage;
        } else {
            System.out.println("moving down");
            currentStage = stage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply add `public static void main(String[] args){Elevator();}` to your code

Answer (score 2):

when you run java it runs `main` method that i don't see in your class so basically eclipse is telling you: "what do you want me to run?", you should implement it:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found another error.

```
  public int  (int carry) // Setting carry into the elevator
{
    currentCarr = carry;
    if (currentCarr != 0) {
        fillCondition = true;
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Method can't be called **'int'**. This name is reserved by the Java language.

Answer (score 1):

When developing a core-java application, all you need to do is to have a **main** method (ofcourse with the functionality :P) in it which is the first code fragment JVM Searches for when you try to run your application. For the above code, try this:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {

//Now, make an instance of your class to instantiate it.

Elevator obj = new Elevator();

//Then,as per the desired functionality. Call the methods in your class using the reference.

//obj.move(val of stage);

obj.move(10);
}
```

Just make sure to have a main method for executing your java code. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

the access point for java is the main method.. every program must access from a main method.
and in main method, you need to create an instance of your class to use the method inside main method like following:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
  Elevator elevator = new Elevator();
  elevator.move(1);
  ...
}
```

and also `public int  (int carry) // Setting carry into the elevator` is not valid format in Java, you have to define a method name like

```
public int setCarry(int carry) // Setting carry{
  //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't run a Java program without

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

The program only executs the main method. In the main method you can create objects like

```
Elevator elevator = new Elevator();
```

You can put the main method anywhere.